# Javascript how to retrieve last digit with separator -

Tags: javascript

i have data string

```
generate-image-scanID-60
generate-image-scanID-4
```

how to retrieve last digit with separator - ? in javascript

ouput :

- 60
- 4

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can combine `String.split()` and `Array.at()` to do it

```js
let datas =['generate-image-scanID-60','generate-image-scanID-4']
const getData = v => v.split('-').at(-1)

datas.forEach(d => {
  console.log(getData(d))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string and get last element and parse int

```js
const raw = ['generate-image-scanID-60', 'generate-image-scanID-4']

const result = raw.map(str => parseInt(str.split('-').at(-1), 10))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use **regex** also :

```js
let arr = ["generate-image-scanID-60", "generate-image-scanID-40"];

let t = arr.map((x) => +x.match(/^.*-(\d+)/)[1]);

console.log(t);
```